# Rails - How to access tables from external Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to get some data from external db(Not the primary one). So I added a connection entry in database.yml.

```
external_reporting_table:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: reporting_db
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: password
```

Also I've created a class to address it, external_reporting_db.rb

```
class ExternalReportingDB < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :external_reporting_table
end
```

I've this model I need to get the data from external db, custom_report.rb

```
class CustomReport < ExternalReportingDB
  def self.shop_data_collection_abstract(batch_selections)
    p "Here I need to get multiple data from external db's tables."
  end
end
```

What should I do to access a table from external db in custom_report.rb ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I do this, I do it according to what ActiveRecord expects which is a single model class per table. For example, let's say my external db has a table called customers, then I would define a class called "ExternalCustomers" and set the establish_connection and the table name inside the class. Here's an example:

```
class ExternalCustomer < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :external_reporting_table
  table_name "customers"
end
```

Then you can use it as you would any other AR model:

```
ExternalCustomer.where(id: 123)
```

If you don't want to add new models for every table, you can query the external db through the connection. Example:

```
ExternalReportingDB.connection.execute("select * from whatever...")
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this method, I'm looking for any other way to handle external DB tables without creating additional models.

Comment: @AlbertPaul This is the Rails way. Why wouldn't you want to use ActiveRecord?